# How can I create a mapping with control and a function key in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to have a mapping to quickly quit all buffers, for use when I'm vimdiffing a lot of files.  Control and a function key together proved a good safety, so that I don't accidentally hit this combination, unintentionally leaving Vim.  I tried the following mapping:

```
map <C-F10> :qa<CR>
```

To no avail.  If I ditch the control, I can quit with F10 alone—why doesn't control work with F10 in my mapping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are using vim and not gvim. vim keybindings are limited by the terminal we are running vim within.

I've given up on vim, and I systematically use gvim for that reason.

Comment: Yep, it's a terminal issue.  The big reason I've stuck with vim over gvim, is that I can run it within screen and thus get more virtual desktop space.  I guess I'll just have to get more virtual desktops!

Comment: I use MacVim (gui vim for OS X) and wasn't able to get a combined ctrl + function key mapping to work, fyi.  I also had to remember to map using `nmap` for "normal mode" mapping to get my bash command shortcut to work from inside my vim session.

Answer (score 1):

Luc is right - I just tried that in gvim (well, MacVim) and it worked fine. Then I tried it in the terminal with no joy.