# vim macro mapping

Tags: vim, vim-macros

In Vim, how would I set up a macro for Ctrl+Shift+another key? I did noremap  and the mapping practically ignored the shift. I could press  and the macro would go through.

Comment: What is "another key"? Remember that Shift+4=$, for example :)

Comment: BTW, I haven't vote for closing the question, but AFAIK this is exactly the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703785/how-can-i-create-a-mapping-with-control-and-a-function-key-in-vim

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing the actual commands you're using.  What does your noremap command look like, something like this?:

```
noremap <s-c-F8> :[command here]<CR>
```

Comment: This should not make any difference. With gvim, on my XP box, ctrl-v+ctrl-shift-f8 displays <C-S-F8>. And yet, when I map <S-C-F8> I have the correct result, and the other way around is true as well. But the best demonstration is the following: mab something to <c-s-f8>, map something else to <s-c-f8>, and then ask vim what it has mapped for both.

Comment: @Luc -- Thanks, I had  problem some months ago and was left thinking the order mattered.  Must have been some other problem I actually had.  In any case wanted to get some code out there as example so we get some idea of what OP is actually doing. . . [ revised post to take out suggestion that ordering matters]

Comment: I am trying to use the same hotkey for text pasting in gvim as in the terminal. I don't want to remember two different macro shortcut for the same function.